# Rounding the coeffcients in a polynomial

Tags: numerics

I have a very large polynomial with Complex Numbers as coefficients.  Due to many calculations, there are rounding off errors.  I know however by theoretical considerations, that the coefficients are integers and almost all of them give 0.  I use `Round`, `Chop` to do it but to no avail.  `Chop` for example let me see `1. + 3. x` but in reality the internal Reals behind them are `1.00003` or `2.0000002` etc.
I must do something wrong.  If I do `Round[0.00001]` everything goes fine.  But not if I do 
`Round[0.00001 + 0.00002 x]`, nothing usefull happens.

Comment: [Welcome to Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help). You can [improve your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) by adding an example of the code you are working on that shows the problem.

Answer (score 5):

[eldo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14254/eldo) already posed and deleted something like this, but I think it works well in many cases:

```
poly = Expand @ FromDigits[RandomComplex[2 + 2 I, 6], x];

poly /. n_?NumberQ :> Round[n]
```

> ```
> (1 + I) + (1 + I) x + I x^2 + (1 + I) x^3 + x^4 + (1 + I) x^5
> ```

Note that this will round exponents as well.  More robust is the method of rhermans, which might also be written in terms of [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientRules.html):

```
MapAt[Round, CoefficientRules[poly], {All, 2}] ~FromCoefficientRules~ x
```

> ```
> (1 + I) + (1 + I) x + I x^2 + (1 + I) x^3 + x^4 + (1 + I) x^5
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You don't give an example so I create my own:

```
poly = Expand@FromDigits[RandomComplex[2 + 2 I, 6], x]
```

> (0.117797 + 
>      0.674094 I) + (0.980296 + 1.90575 I) x + (0.190167 + 
>       1.68039 I) x^2 + (1.65725 + 1.83193 I) x^3 + (1.07084 + 
>       1.19757 I) x^4 + (0.473445 + 1.37764 I) x^5

---

Probably you can extract your coefficients first, and then round them

```
Round @ CoefficientList[poly,x]
```

> {I, 1 + 2 I, 2 I, 2 + 2 I, 1 + I, I}

and then reconstruct the polynomial.

```
Expand@FromDigits[Reverse[%], x]
```

> I + (1 + 2 I) x + 2 I x^2 + (2 + 2 I) x^3 + (1 + I) x^4 + I x^5

---

A more general solution would be to have a way to map a function over the coefficients directly

```
polyMap[f_, poly_, var_] := 
 Expand@FromDigits[
 Reverse[Map[f, CoefficientList[poly, var]]
 ], var]
```

another data example:

```
poly2 = Expand@FromDigits[9 RandomComplex[1 + I, 4], x]
```

> ```
> (2.92741 +  7.78658 I) + (5.17754 + 3.29475 I) x + (4.93425 +  2.98767 I) x^2 + (6.71465 + 1.91807 I) x^3
> ```

Now we map `Round` over the coefficients

```
polyMap[Round, poly2, x]
```

> (3 + 8 I) + (5 + 3 I) x + (5 + 3 I) x^2 + (7 + 2 I) x^3

but we could also `Map` other functions such as `Ceiling` or `Floor`

```
polyMap[Floor, poly2, x]
```

> (2 + 7 I) + (5 + 3 I) x + (4 + 2 I) x^2 + (6 + I) x^3

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to reconstruct a polynomial from a coefficients list, but it works. Improvements are welcomed.

Comment: `FromDigits` seems good but an alternative is to use `CoefficientRules`.  See my answer below.  (+1)